# »Fahren in der Nähe« oder »fahren in die Nähe«?

Tags: verb, dative, accusative

Etwas sagt mir, dass »Fahren in der Nähe« die richtige Wahl ist.

> *Zusammenhang*: Ich habe Lust, nur in der Nähe zu fahren.

Trotztdem kann ich das nicht erklären, da *fahren* ein Bewegungsverb ist.

- Was ist in diesem Beispiel *in der Nähe*?
- Soll ich es als ein Teil eines Verbes betrachten?
- Oder ist *in der Nähe* einfach kein Objekt, denn es stillscheigend lautet

> Ich habe Lust, nur *irgendwohin* in der Nähe zu fahren.

wobei *irgendwohin* eigentlich das Objekt in Akkusativ ist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beide Varianten sind korrekt. Sie haben allerdings eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung.

> Ich habe Lust, nur in der Nähe zu fahren.

Hier bedeutet "in der Nähe" eine begrenzte, statische Umgebung, etwas wie eine Zonenangabe. Wenn du "in der Nähe" zum Beispiel mit "im Schulhof" austauschst, wird klar, dass es sich um eine Ortsergänzung im 3. Fall (Dativ, "wo?") handelt.

Hingegen ist mit

> Ich habe Lust, nur irgendwohin in die Nähe zu fahren.

gemeint, dass in eine Richtung gefahren wird – also *weg* vom gegenwärtigen Standpunkt zu einem Ziel ("wohin?"). *Nähe* drückt in diesem Fall aus, dass das Ziel nicht weit entfernt sein soll.

In der Grammatik nennt man die oben erwähnten Satzglieder *adverbiale Bestimmungen des Ortes* oder *lokale Adverbiale*. Sie erweitern sozusagen das Prädikat (Verb) und antworten auf die Fragen: wo?, wohin? bzw. woher? *("Ich komme aus der Nähe")*

Comment: Nebenbei bemerkt würde ich sagen, dass man eher "Ich habe keine Lust, weit weg zu fahren" sagen würde. Denn "Nähe" ist an sich leer. Die Nähe von was?? Der Kontext klärt es auf, aber nicht sofort und 100%ig

Comment: Nur kurz: ist es aber auch möglich, das *irgendwohin* wegzuwerfen, und einfach *Ich habe Lust, nur in* **die** *Nähe zu fahren* sagen?

Comment: @c.p. ja, das ist möglich. Dein Gesprächspartner wird dich verstehen.